# How can I avoid state of "TypeError: can't access dead object" in my Firefox add-on?

Tags: javascript, object, firefox-addon, mozilla

It seems checking against `null` works, but is it a correct method? How can I correctly check that object is not dead? And where is the definition of dead object?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dead object would mean an object whose parent document has been destroyed, and the references are removed to eliminate memory leaks in add-ons. So you could check for the element, as:

```
if( typeof some_element !== 'undefined') {
    //its not dead
}
```

See [Dead Object Reference](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/09/12/what-does-cant-access-dead-object-mean/)

Comment: This answer is wrong. If `some_element` is referencing an object that no longer exists then what you have there is still a cross-compartment wrapper - albeit one that will throw an exception if you try to use it. So `typeof some_element` will still be `object` and it is non-null value.

Comment: I think the answer is wrong.  I have a DeadObject and it returns true

Answer (score 3):

This is likely due to holding zombie compartments. If you are storing a `window` in a variable you should use weak reference, otherwise it will keep the process alive.

Great read right here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Zombie_compartments

This is how to use weak references:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.getWeakReference

A dead object, is holding a strong (keep alive) reference to a DOM element (usually) that persists even after it was destroyed in the DOM.

Sometimes checking if it is undefined or null does not work, a trick I saw once and use sometimes is to check if parentNode exists (so not null or undefined).

Comment: FYI: The pages linked in this answer are now broken

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use weak references as suggested by [Blagoh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3791822/blagoh), then you can use `Components.utils.isDeadWrapper()` function to check (added in Firefox 17 but still not really documented):

```
if (Components.utils.isDeadWrapper(element))
  alert("I won't touch that, it's a dead object");
```

Unprivileged code doesn't really have a way of recognizing dead objects without triggering an exception. Then again, if an object throws an exception no matter what you do then it is probably dead:

```
try
{
  String(element);
}
catch (e)
{
  alert("Better not touch that, it's likely a dead object");
}
```