# Selenium error on login button:[error] isNewPageLoaded found an old pageLoadError: TypeError: can't access dead object

Tags: selenium

[error] isNewPageLoaded found an old pageLoadError: TypeError: can't access dead object

IDE- 2.8.0 & Fire fox: 34.0

[warn] Stack is: BrowserBot.prototype._handleClosedSubFrame@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js:1251:1 BrowserBot.prototype.getCurrentWindow@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js:1229:18 BrowserBot.prototype.pollForLoad@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js:961:38 BrowserBot.prototype.reschedulePoller/pollerFunction@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js:1099:9 BrowserBot.prototype.runScheduledPollers@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js:1109:9 TestLoop.prototype.continueTestWhenConditionIsTrue@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-executionloop.js:142:9 .continueTestWhenConditionIsTrue@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-runner.js:210:7 fnBind/retval@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/htmlutils.js:60:12
[error] can't access dead object

Please someone guide me to get rid of this error.

Comment: Have you Checked the Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041864/how-can-i-avoid-state-of-typeerror-cant-access-dead-object-in-my-firefox-add

Comment: Hi Rupesh- yes, i checked it but i guess this is on java scripts. As of now am using recording scripts as am new into this and this error i got when i record the scripts and re-run, although all the further steps are working after login but the step which is used to login button is failed. am using latest selenium IDE & Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was introduced in FF 15 and later Versions  where  it does not allow its Add-ons to keep references to DOM objects after their parent Document is destroyed. But there are 2 things which you can try in this case.

**Solution 1** :  *Try to Disable the non-required Add-ons in your browser and re-run the Selenium IDE script.* 
**Solution 2** :  *Nothing wrong with the Script you recorded so try degrading your FF version to older (Better give try with FF 14 older or any ESR versions, Aware its old version and just in case if your comfortable with degrading then only you can try this step).* *or you can try upgrading your browser with ESR version from [here](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/)*